# orphaned inodes on root file system (ext4); persistent problem

Tags: filesystem, ext4, fsck, inode

On my trusty systems (VMs under vmWare, desktops, and laptops), we have the following issue.

The root file system seems to have inodes that are never marked as "free".
After a month of a working server the `df -i` show a 100% usage of inodes on / (an `ext4 fs`).

Doing a preview `fsck` shows errors.
We do a `touch` /`forcefsck`, and reboot the system.
This correct orphaned inodes, but the problem appears again.

There is no messages on `/var/log/syslog`. The systems are up to date with the latest update and kernel availables on Trusty.

```
# fsck -nf /
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Warning!  /dev/mapper/sys--vg-root is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Deleted inode 395860 has zero dtime.  Fix? no

Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix? no

Inode 395869 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 395871 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 395872 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 395873 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 395874 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 395875 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 395877 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 395878 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -1606447 -(1606994--1606995) -1606998 -1607063 -1607094     -1607128 -1607232 -1607687
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong (2346388, counted=2345410).
Fix? no

Inode bitmap differences:  -395860 -395869 -(395871--395875) -(395877--395878)
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong (662804, counted=662787).
Fix? no


/dev/mapper/sys--vg-root: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

/dev/mapper/sys--vg-root: 107244/770048 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 730732/3077120 blocks
```